# MongoDB returning empty array when retrieving collection in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a NodeJS server which looks like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
connstring = 'connectionstring' ##Connection string to MongoDB Atlas
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    next();
});
MongoClient.connect(connstring, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(client => {
        console.log('Connected to Database')
        const db = client.db('dbname')
        const licensplateCollection = db.collection('licenseplate')
        app.get('/get-licenseplates', function(req, res) {
            licensplateCollection.find().toArray()
                .then(results => {
                    console.log("retrieving licenseplates")
                    console.log(results)
                    res.send(results)
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error))
                // do something here
        })
```

When i am trying to get the licenseplates, all i recieve is a empty array. My collection does contain a license plate, tho:

[Screenshot of the collection via MongoDB's website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHwYe.jpg)

Am I missing something? I checked for typos, tried recreating the database multiple times, but it did not help.

Comment: I guess there is an issue with the name of the collection, MongoDB creates a collection in plural form, so try to replace 

const licensplateCollection = db.collection('licenseplate')

with 

const licensplateCollection = db.collection('licenseplates')

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it did not work. Same result as before

Answer (score 0):

i think problem at network access , make sure you added ip at network access

[image]

Comment: The error would be different if that is the case. It won't connect to the DB

Comment: Unfortunately thats not the problem, i gave access to all ip addresses

Comment: I wish i could help u . i do same example in my pc with local db & worked .  ( so , i think about ip address) @Schwammal